# Peculiar external spigot replacement needed

Tags: plumbing

I have the following spigot and it appears that there is no way to access the piping that leads to it. I am used to the typical silkcock style but this one I've never seen before. Is it removable from the front?

PS: The reason why it needs to be changed is that it leaks through all the holes in the front which renders having a hose pretty much useless.

[image]

Comment: I googled this for you: http://www.woodfordmfg.com/woodford/wfdindex.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. So this does explain the splashing. Is there a way that this can be replaced with a quarter valve from the outside. On the other side, there is just a cement basement wall so I wonder how was this installed.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a repair kit for this:
http://www.woodfordmfg.com/woodford/Troubleshooting/25%20-%2027%20Troubleshooting.pdf

The model in question is 20 but the 25 kit is supported by it. It can be replaced from the front.